# Error building app with importet .jar file

Tags: android, gradle, jar

In my project I imported jar file which was coded and exported in Eclipse. When I'm trying to run app I got error:

[image]

And here is my gradle file:

[image]

I tryed to add targetCompatibility and sourceCompatibility but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I configure build.gradle as follows and it started working.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
    ...
       jackOptions {
           enabled true
       }
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Java 1.8 and set following in build.gradle file

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion 23
     buildToolsVersion 24rc3

     defaultConfig {
    ...        
         jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
   dexOptions {
    incremental true
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to add in defaultConfig{multiDexEnabled true} and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

You should download and use Java 8. It says `This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.`

You should always read the error you receive from the compiler

Comment: I already using java from "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102"

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` file

Comment: Isn't that file on second picture in my question?

Comment: If so please read the following documentation : `https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html#configuration`

Comment: I resolved it with similarly code that is in @Jaymin Panchal answer.

Comment: Can you close this question? By selecting an answer?

Comment: I upovoted his answer, but it didn't totally correct so I didnt accpet it as right answer.

Comment: So post Ur own solution as answer and close the question

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
         targetCompatibility = "1.7"
   }
}
```

This worked for me.